# Error after upgrading Apache Superset - RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: upgrade, apache-superset

I just upgraded to newest version of Apache Superset.
When I start Apache Superset with the command

```
gunicorn \
      -w 10 \
      -k gevent \
      --timeout 120 \
      -b  0.0.0.0:8088 \
      --limit-request-line 0 \
      --limit-request-field_size 0 \
      --statsd-host localhost:8088 \
      superset:app
```

I get the error "Internal server error"
On the server it says:

```
 respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/superset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 376, in <lambda>
    __call__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/superset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/superset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

...

I found out that it I changed to "superset.app:create_app()"  I could login, like this:

```
gunicorn \
      -w 10 \
      -k gevent \
      --timeout 120 \
      -b  0.0.0.0:8088 \
      --limit-request-line 0 \
      --limit-request-field_size 0 \
      --statsd-host localhost:8088 \
"superset.app:create_app()"
```

But When I open a dashboard I now get this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/superset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'slices.schema_perm' in 'field list'")
[SQL: SELECT slices.created_on AS slices_created_on, slices.changed_on AS slices_changed_on, slices.id AS slices_id, slices.slice_name AS slices_slice_name, slices.datasource_id AS slices_datasource_id, slices.datasource_type AS slices_datasource_type, slices.datasource_name AS slices_datasource_name, slices.viz_type AS slices_viz_type, slices.params AS slices_params, slices.description AS slices_description, slices.cache_timeout AS slices_cache_timeout, slices.perm AS slices_perm, slices.schema_perm AS slices_schema_perm, slices.created_by_fk AS slices_created_by_fk, slices.changed_by_fk AS slices_changed_by_fk, tables_1.created_on AS tables_1_created_on, tables_1.changed_on AS tables_1_changed_on, tables_1.id AS tables_1_id, tables_1.description AS tables_1_description, tables_1.default_endpoint AS tables_1_default_endpoint, tables_1.is_featured AS tables_1_is_featured, tables_1.filter_select_enabled AS tables_1_filter_select_enabled, tables_1.offset AS tables_1_offset, tables_1.cache_timeout AS tables_1_cache_timeout, tables_1.params AS tables_1_params, tables_1.perm AS tables_1_perm, tables_1.schema_perm AS tables_1_schema_perm, tables_1.table_name AS tables_1_table_name, tables_1.main_dttm_col AS tables_1_main_dttm_col, tables_1.database_id AS tables_1_database_id, tables_1.fetch_values_predicate AS tables_1_fetch_values_predicate, tables_1.`schema` AS tables_1_schema, tables_1.`sql` AS tables_1_sql, tables_1.is_sqllab_view AS tables_1_is_sqllab_view, tables_1.template_params AS tables_1_template_params, tables_1.created_by_fk AS tables_1_created_by_fk, tables_1.changed_by_fk AS tables_1_changed_by_fk 
FROM dashboard_slices, slices LEFT OUTER JOIN `tables` AS tables_1 ON slices.datasource_id = tables_1.id AND slices.datasource_type = %s 
WHERE %s = dashboard_slices.dashboard_id AND slices.id = dashboard_slices.slice_id]
[parameters: ('table', 7)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I have searched more for a solution. It seems that my MySQL-database is not corrected with the upgrade, when using the db upgrade command:

```
(superset) [root@host .superset]# superset db upgrade
logging was configured successfully
INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
/usr/local/superset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:188: UserWarning: Flask-Cache: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn("Flask-Cache: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, "
WARNI [alembic.env] SQLite Database support for metadata databases will         be removed in a future version of Superset.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

I dont see any errors?

When I call init I get this:

```
(superset) [root@host .superset]# superset init
logging was configured successfully
INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
/usr/local/superset/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:188: UserWarning: Flask-Cache: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn("Flask-Cache: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, "
Syncing role definition
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing role definition
Syncing Admin perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Admin perms
Syncing Alpha perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Alpha perms
Syncing Gamma perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Gamma perms
Syncing granter perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing granter perms
Syncing sql_lab perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing sql_lab perms
Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
INFO:superset.security.manager:Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
Creating missing datasource permissions.
INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing datasource permissions.
Creating missing database permissions.
INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing database permissions.
Creating missing metrics permissions
INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing metrics permissions
Cleaning faulty perms
INFO:superset.security.manager:Cleaning faulty perms
```

Is it because superset needs some permission to MySQL to make the changes in tables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the command 'superset db upgrade' didn't update my MYSQL-database, but I then manually created these fields and tables and now it seems to be working:

```
slices.schema_perm
tables.schema_perm
dbs.encrypted_extra
dbs.allow_cvas
dbs.server_cert
saved_query.extra_json
```

And these tables with fields

```
CREATE TABLE `alerts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crontab` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sql` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alert_type` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipients` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_retention` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grace_period` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dashboard_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `database_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_eval_dttm` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_state` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `alerts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

CREATE TABLE `tab_state` (
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `changed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_json` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `database_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schema` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sql` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `query_limit` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latest_query_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `autorun` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `template_params` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `changed_by_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I don't know the field types, so maybe someone can help with the correct types.